# Print n max character / line with python print file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, printing

I need help in order to print some content in a file and not exeed specific number of character / line.

So for instance let say I have the folowing dataframe ;

**df**

```
COL1   COL2 
VALUE1 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
VALUE2 QRSTUVWXYZ
```

and then usualy I do

```
with open("my_file.txt","w") as output:
 for row in df.rows:
   print ('>',row[col1],sep="",file=output)
   print (row[col2],file=output
```

and get :

```
>VALUE1 
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
>VALUE2
QRSTUVWXYZ
```

but how to say "I just want to print max 7 character/lines ? and get :

```
>VALUE1 
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
OP
>VALUE2
QRSTUVW
XYZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using : `(textwrap.fill(row[col2], width=7))`